# Is there a way to convert a time delay into a sample delay?

Tags: filter, time, digital-filter

I have been given a time delay of a signal and the sampling frequency, however, I am trying to calculate the delay in samples. My logic is: delay frequency divided by sampling frequency, however, this doesn't give integer answers, which is what I expected as this is the time at which each sample is taken. However, if I do sampling frequency divided by delay frequency it gives integers for the sampling delay, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Could anyone  please explain the conversion between delay in time and delay in samples.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you talking about "delay frequency"? You have a delay (seconds) and a sampling frequency (samples / seconds). Just look at the units.

Comment: So it's the sampling frequency divided by the delay time? @Mat

Comment: What are the units for what you propose?

Comment: sampling frequency is in Hz and time delay in seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the time delay and the sampling frequency. The reciprocal of the sampling frequency is the time between samples. Thus if you divide the time delay by the time between samples (using the same units such as seconds), you will get the delay in units of sample periods. This should result in an integer (within the tolerances of the time delay and sampling frequency).

Comment: Right ok, this makes sense, and it works in giving integer values. Thank you very much